# How to disable or hide scrollbar/minimap?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can't find any option, setting, or keyboard shortcut that disables or hides that annoying scrollbar. I just don't find it useful and it's distracting.

Can't just edit the editor's CSS like Atom, either.

Answer (score 352, accepted):

## Remove Minimap

Add the following to your `settings.json` file

```
"editor.minimap.enabled": false
```

*Note that, as pointed out in another answer, this process has now been simplified to:*

```
View->Show Minimap
```

## Remove the Overview Ruler

Add the following to your `settings.json` file

```
"editor.hideCursorInOverviewRuler": true
```

This will keep the scrollbar, but will result in it only appearing when the cursor is within the editor, as seen in the image below:

[image]

## Completely remove scrollbars (requires restart)

If you would like to completely remove the scrollbars, add the following to your `settings.json` file (note the editor will say "Unknown configuration setting" - ignore this. It will still work):

```
"editor.scrollbar.horizontal": "hidden",
"editor.scrollbar.vertical": "hidden"
```

This will result in the scrollbars not being visible even when the cursor is in the editor, as seen in the image below:

[image]

Comment: hmm. those "editor.scrollbar.*" entries give me "Unknown configuration setting"

Comment: You need to restart vscode. It's an unoffical method to hid scroll bars that's why giving that error. [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/35454)

Comment: To make these scrollbars appear to hide, you can use RGBA colouring for `scrollbarSlider` attributes in your `workbench.colorCustomizations` settings. For example, setting all of the attributes to `#000000`.

Comment: On my system it's `view `-> `show minimap` Not sure if this was changed since then or if it's a difference between OS builds

Comment: For me, the "editor.scrollbar.vertical": "hidden" didnt work, but the horizontal did!

Answer (score 175):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> -> `Open User Settings`

```json
"editor.minimap.enabled": false
```

Comment: This should be the default setting. same for the the file preview that closes a file when you open a new one. thanks

Answer (score 59):

Try this,

`view->toggle minimap`

or after version 1.43

`view->show minimap`

Answer (score 20):

**Removing the scroll bar**

These no longer work:

```
"editor.scrollbar.horizontal": "hidden",
"editor.scrollbar.vertical": "hidden"
```

However, this will set the size of the scroll bar to 0:

```
"editor.scrollbar.verticalScrollbarSize": 0,
```

The toolip says "Unknown Configuration Setting" but it works for me.
(Visual Studio Code 1.39.2)

Comment: As of 2022, there is a Setting: `Editor › Scrollbar: Vertical Scrollbar Size`.  I set it to `0` (zero) and the entire scrollbar column was no longer visible.  (Which is the result I wanted.)

Answer (score 11):

So this is an unofficial method as instructed on accepted answer by @badfilms. You can read about it [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/35454)

After adding, restart vscode:

`"editor.scrollbar.horizontal": "hidden",
"editor.scrollbar.vertical": "hidden"`

This gives and "Unknown configuration settings", ignore it.

Then to remove the scrollbar seperator or ruler border, add this:

`"editor.overviewRulerBorder": false`

Answer (score 11):

Goto **View** and deselect **Minimap**.

[image: Disable Minimap in VSCode]

Comment: Right on the head. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

tested Visual Studio version:  VS Community 2017 Version 15.8.2

Tools --> Options

Search for "scroll"

click on "Text Editor" title from the results on the left side.

click "Use bar mode for vertical scroll bar" under "Behavior" section  and then click "OK"

Here is a screenshot:
[image: Turn off Scroll Bar map mode]

Answer (score 5):

You can toggle it from the top bar "View > Show Minimap",
But you can also define it as a keyboard shortcut!

1. Go to: "File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts"
2. Search: "Minimap"
3. Select: "View: Toggle Minimap"
4. Select the keyboard you wish to link (I used Ctrl+M)

Comment: Good suggestion to assign a keyboard shortcut to it, while working using split up screen minimap is not required as it takes up a lot of space.

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio 2019
Right click on the scroll bar and select "Scroll Bar Options" from the context menu.
This will display the settings for the Scroll Bars.

Under the Behavior heading halfway down, select "Use bar mode for vertical scroll bar"  then click Ok.  This removed the map mode from the bar.

Comment: this question is About vs-code not Studio 2019

Comment: Considering this post helped me find a solution to question in regular VS, I figured it might help others who show up here.  There are generally a lot of feature cross over between Microsoft programs, which means possible settings that also crossed over.

Comment: To be fair, the question doesn't specify whether it's VS Code or Studio, unless it's been edited as of today, 03/16/2022. As I was looking for an answer on how to remove the scroll bar for Visual Studio, this answer worked for me. I am using VS 2022 also

Answer (score 3):

As of Version 1.79.0-insider it's:

```
View > Appearance > Minimap
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

View --> Show Minimap -click it to uncheck it-

Answer (score 2):

Just to update the situation, in the past the settings mentioned above worked, despite showing an unknown configuration error, after a reload, because they had not been officially exposed to users. With v1.58 these settings will be "official" and not require a reload.

```
editor.scrollbar.vertical - 'auto' | 'visible' | 'hidden'
editor.scrollbar.horizontal - 'auto' | 'visible' | 'hidden'
editor.scrollbar.verticalScrollbarSize - number
editor.scrollbar.horizontalScrollbarSize - number
editor.scrollbar.scrollByPage - boolean
```

See [Expose editor scrollbar options and react to them being updated](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/127788).

Answer (score 0):

once you go to the user setting it has default setting left had side as bellow and 
there is a pensile mark on where click and automatically appear true false then right had side custom setting change. Thats how I did it thanks Alexandru.
think this may help you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Default value of Scroll Beyond Last Column is 5 which does horizontal scrollbar visible and operate. Set the value to 0 removes horizontal scrollbar.

[Settings options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a05En.png)

Answer (score 0):

for hidden scroll bar add into setting.json

```
`"window.scrollBarVisibility": "hidden",`
```

for hidden minimap add :

```
"editor.minimap.enabled": false,
```

Answer (score 0):

**For all projects**

Write to a *search settings*:

[image: write "scrollbar" to a search settings]

Then change *this values* as on screenshot:

[image: change vertical and horizontal values to hidden or 0 accordingly]