# How to make scrollbars wider in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to make Visual Studio Code's window scrollbars wider? I'm finding they're a few pixels too skinny compared to other apps and my mouse often misses the precise location that I'm trying to click.

Comment: You might want to watch this: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/30191

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68233096/836330 for an update on `editor.scrollbar.verticalScrollbarSize` setting in vscode v1.58.

Answer (score 22):

I am using Visual Studio Code 1.58.2 on Windows 10 OS.

1. Open the menu: File -> Preferences -> Settings.
2. A Settings tab will be open. In the search box, type in **title scrollbar sizing**.
3. Change the dropdown list value from **default** to **large**.
4. Close Settings tab.
5. DONE! Congratulations.

If you want to test it, open multiple files and you will see the horizontal scrollbar at the top is wider and easier to pick by the mouse pointer.

Answer (score 17):

@andr its only for vertical,
the complete set

```
,"editor.scrollbar.verticalScrollbarSize": 10
,"editor.scrollbar.horizontal": "visible"
,"editor.scrollbar.horizontalScrollbarSize": 15
```

, and [workaround](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/32192#issuecomment-450222349) using an exceptionally meaningful [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css#review-details) ,for **tabs group scrollbar**

(to insert in **custom.css**):

```
/*tab group scrollbar;*/
.monaco-workbench>.part.editor>.content .editor-group-container>.title.tabs>.tabs-and-actions-container>.monaco-scrollable-element .scrollbar,
.monaco-workbench>.part.editor>.content .editor-group-container>.title.tabs>.tabs-and-actions-container>.monaco-scrollable-element .scrollbar .slider {
    height: 20px !important;
}

/*scrollbars;
.monaco-workbench>.part.editor>.content .editor-group-container>.editor-container .monaco-scrollable-element .scrollbar
, .monaco-workbench>.part.editor>.content .editor-group-container>.editor-container .monaco-scrollable-element .scrollbar .slider {
    height: 20px !important;
}
*/
```

Comment: note: latest VSC above didnt work. specifically this part: 
.monaco-workbench>.part.editor
didnt' work, needed a slight modification:
.monaco-workbench .part.editor

Comment: @armyofda12mnkeys ,
`.monaco-workbench .part.editor` and removing all `>` still doesn't work

Answer (score 10):

As of VS Code 1.48.0, the following line in settings.json helped me to make horizontal scrollbar larger:

```
"workbench.editor.titleScrollbarSizing": "large"
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to edit the file %APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json and add

```
,"editor.scrollbar.verticalScrollbarSize": 15
,"editor.scrollbar.horizontalScrollbarSize": 15
```

Comment: And ignore the "Unknown Configuration Setting" that VS Code throws at you, it works regardless.

Answer (score 5):

Since VSCode's June 2021 release (version 1.58) the scrollbar can be edited directly in the settings (get there faster by pressing ctr+,) and searching for `editor.scrollbar`. You can change the vertical scrollbar's size there.

[image: Release notese on scrollbar settings]

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why this one isn't set to this size by default to match the others.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Dai for the link. The undocumented property `editor.scrollbar.verticalScrollbarSize` handles this for the code windows. It doesn't affect the scrollbars on the file explorer, but that's OK for now.

Answer (score 1):

You can also have the open tabs wrap and not scroll:

```
"workbench.editor.wrapTabs": true
```