# Visual Studio Code: Expand the horizontal bar for scrolling tabs

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to know if there is a way in Visual Studio Code to enlarge the tabs scrollbar that I find too small.

Picture :

[Horizontal bar for scrolling tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xcW2.png)

Comment: Please ask questions in English..thank you

Answer (score 15):

This is being fixed in v1.44 - due out early March 2020.   See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/92720 (Allow users to make the scrollbars in the title area larger #92720).  And https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_44.md#new-setting-to-control-height-of-tabs-scrollbar

[image: large tab scroll bar]

> workbench.editor.titleScrollbarSizing: default | large

You'll be able to set it to `large`.

Comment: @Philip  ` "workbench.editor.titleScrollbarSizing": "large",` in your settings.json - it is at least 6 times larger (in height) for me.

Comment: Ok sorry i didn't see that

Answer (score 5):

Another method: in VSCODE's settings, it's filed under ***Workbench › Editor: Title Scrollbar Sizing***. You can set it to 'large' instead of default. Picture attached. [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwVEp.png)

Answer (score 1):

[workaround](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/32192#issuecomment-450222349) using an exceptionally meaningful [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css#review-details)

(to insert in **custom.css**):

```
/*tab group scrollbar;*/
.monaco-workbench>.part.editor>.content .editor-group-container>.title.tabs>.tabs-and-actions-container>.monaco-scrollable-element .scrollbar,
.monaco-workbench>.part.editor>.content .editor-group-container>.title.tabs>.tabs-and-actions-container>.monaco-scrollable-element .scrollbar .slider {
    height: 20px !important;
}
```

[How to make scrollbars wider in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50106972/how-to-make-scrollbars-wider-in-visual-studio-code/54392013#54392013)

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: note: latest VSC above didnt work. specifically this part: 
.monaco-workbench>.part.editor
didnt' work, needed a slight modification:
.monaco-workbench .part.editor