# How to disable Code Preview/Map next to scrollbar in Visual Studio (2019) for Python

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Note: this is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40891692/any-way-to-disable-or-hide-visual-studio-codes-scrollbar-minimap) (it's for VS Code, I am asking for Visual Studio - 2019 Community if it's applicable)

I am new to Python (from C# .NET background) and when switching to Python I notice this huge bar next to the scrollbar:

[image]

<s>What are they called? How do I disable them?</s> And why does Python environment have them (I have never seen them before when using C#), is it helpful for common scenario and should I really disable them if I could?

I have looked in Options for Python, does not see anything that may be useful.

**EDIT**: Found the option, it is in Text Editor > Python > Scroll Bars (not top-level Python section, but under Text Editor). In the Behavior section, I changed `Source overview` option to `Off` and it's like C# now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the option, it is in Text Editor > Python > Scroll Bars (not top-level Python section, but under Text Editor). In the Behavior section, I changed `Source overview` option to `Off` and it's like C# now.

[image]

Comment: Great thanks - no idea who thinks that preview thing is helpful!